# SQLITE: Search and Replace with wildcard

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database with a table called "tvshow", and the data in column c10 of this table needs to be replaced in the form of:

ORIGINAL DATA:

```
<episodeguide><url cache="78984.xml">http://www.thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/78984/all/en.zip</url></episodeguide>
```

NEW DATA REQUIRED:

```
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:78984}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>
```

So I need to use a wildcard or regex pattern to replace where what occurs in the original data after the first double quote and before .xml; and again the same string between series/ and /all (which is 78984 in the example data, and varies for each of the thousands of records in the db), gets stored as a wildcard string and transfered to the correct place in the replacement string.

ALSO: in some cases, the first occurrence of the wildcard number in original string includes "-en" at the end of the number, but I don't need that transferred, so in the example case, the original string would look like:

```
<episodeguide><url cache="74371-en.xml">http://thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/74371/all/en.zip</url></episodeguide>
```

These cases also need to be transfered to the new format, without the "-en".

I know how to do a simple string replacement in the form of:

```
update tvshow set 
  c10= replace(c10, 'originalstring', 'replacementstring')
```

However the more complex replacement is beyond my simple skills.

Could someone please help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following will do what you wish (or at least close to what you wish and could therefore be the basis of a solution).

- **Note** this does assume that the table is a standard table (rowid table) i.e. that it hasn't been defined using **WITHOUT ROWID**

:-

```
/* Update */
UPDATE mytable AS x SET c10 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(c10,'-en.xml') > 0 THEN 
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
         -- handle -en.xml
        ELSE
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://'),'www.','api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
    END
    WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM mytable WHERE instr(c10,' post="') < 1)
;
```

## Example

The following was used to test the above :-

```
/* Create Test Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (c10 TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
('<episodeguide><url cache="78984.xml">http://www.thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/78984/all/en.zip</url></episodeguide>'),
('<episodeguide><url cache="55555.xml">http://www.someotherthetvdb.com/api/349DFEBA9D3059C6/series/55555/all/en.zip</url></episodeguide>'),
('<episodeguide><url cache="74371-en.xml">http://thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/74371/all/en.zip</url></episodeguide>')
;

/* Update */
UPDATE mytable SET c10 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(c10,'-en.xml') > 0 THEN 
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
         -- handle -en.xml
        ELSE
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://'),'www.','api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
    END

WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid FROM mytable WHERE instr(c10,' post="') < 1)
;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
```

- Note 2nd line added for testing a different base.

## Result

The result of the above was :-

```
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:78984}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.someotherthetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;349DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:55555}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:74371}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>
```

[image]

## Alternative

An alternative is to use a Common Table Expression (CTE) for list of rowids e.g. :-

```
/* Alternative using a CTE (Common Table Expression) */
WITH cte(rowid) AS (
    /* Get the rowid's for the rows to be updated */ 
    SELECT rowid FROM  mytable WHERE instr(c10,' post="') < length(' post="')
)
UPDATE mytable SET c10 = 
    CASE 
        WHEN instr(c10,'-en.xml') > 0 THEN 
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
         -- handle -en.xml
        ELSE
            '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">'||
              replace(replace(
                        substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://'),instr(c10,'/api/') - instr(c10,'http://'))
                    ,'http://','https://'),'www.','api.')
                || '/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/')))
                || '&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'         
                || substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/')))         
                || '}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>'
    END
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT(rowid) FROM cte); /* rowid must be a rowid in the cte */
```

## Additional

If the table (or an alternative) were only to contain the pertinent changable data (API number, API key, address and the code (-en or not)). Then there would bee no need to perform such complicated updates. Rather if the end result changes then it would be reltively simply to change the end result via a changed query. The added advantage is that there would be a relatively large reduction is the disk space required to store the data which. This could then result in improved efficiency (fewer pages, more data chached).

So perhaps consider such an alternative table, which could be created from the existing data using :-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable2 (C40 INTEGER /*NUMBER*/, C41 TEXT /*APIKEY*/, C42 /*CORE WEB ADDRESS */, C43 /*Access Flag*/);

/* Load the alternative table with just the changable data */
INSERT INTO mytable2  
    SELECT 
        substr(c10,instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'),instr(c10,'/all/') - (instr(c10,'/series/') + length('/series/'))),
        substr(c10,instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'),instr(c10,'/series/') - (instr(c10,'/api/') + length('/api/'))),
        replace(substr(c10,instr(c10,'http://') + length('http://'),instr(c10,'/api') - (instr(c10,'http://') + length('http://'))),'www.',''),
        CASE
            WHEN instr(c10,'-en') THEN '-en'
            ELSE ''
        END
    FROM mytable
;
/* Display the alternative table */
SELECT * FROM mytable2;
```

The stored data would (based upon the example data) be :-

[image]

A query to extract both types could be :-

```
/* Extract both types of end data from the alternative table */
SELECT 
    '<episodeguide><url cache="'||C43||C40||'.xml">http://'||

    CASE 
            WHEN length(C43) < 1 THEN 'www.' ELSE ''
        END
    ||C42||'/api/'||C41||'/series/'||C40||'/en.zip</url></episodeguide>' AS type1,
    '<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.'||C42||'/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;'||C41||'&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:'||C40||'}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>' AS type2
FROM mytable2;
```

The result being :-

```
type2   type1
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:78984}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide> <episodeguide><url cache="78984.xml">http://www.thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/78984/en.zip</url></episodeguide>
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.someotherthetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;349DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:55555}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>    <episodeguide><url cache="55555.xml">http://www.someotherthetvdb.com/api/349DFEBA9D3059C6/series/55555/en.zip</url></episodeguide>
<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:74371}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide> <episodeguide><url cache="-en74371.xml">http://thetvdb.com/api/439DFEBA9D3059C6/series/74371/en.zip</url></episodeguide>
```

Comment: Thanks, this mostly works (IE, the records with the old format seem to be correctly updated to the new format), HOWEVER, the query is also changing some records that already had the correct format and stripping out all of their identifier info.

Comment: IE, records that looked like [code]<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">https://api.thetvdb.com/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;439DFEBA9D3059C6&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:330500}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>[/code]

Comment: get changed to [code]<episodeguide><url post="yes" cache="auth.json">/login?{&quot;apikey&quot;:&quot;<epi&quot;,&quot;id&quot;:<episod}|Content-Type=application/json</url></episodeguide>[/code]

Comment: @BrianPeter edited to weed out existing changed rows, assuming **post="** indicates such rows. A few other changes have also been made. However, the answer is **in-principle** as per (*the basis of a solution*). You should be able to get an exact solution from the answer.

Comment: ...Also, I can't change the structure of the data.  This is for a media center program where the URL and format to the API data has changed for old records and needs to be updated in the database for those to scrape the correct data from the web.  So I need to run the replace in-place in the existing table.

Comment: The edited version does not work at all now, it makes no changes. I'm totally lost - I have zero programming experience with SQL.  Perhaps the "-en" was a red herring that is complicating things unnecessarily.  Since I don't need to retain it, I have run a simple pre-search query and just removed it.  Can we start again with a less complicated query that will just change the old to new format?  The first version was really close, but was changing the records that were already correct as an unintended result.

Comment: @BrianPeter as the example shows, based upon the supplied information it DOES do what you want (or at least close to it). You've probably run on the real data updated it and then trying to run on the already updated data. You need to test using a copy of the real data and only apply to the real data when you are confident that it works. If not using a SQLite management tool such as DB Browser for SQlite, Navicat, DB Beaver then you should get and use such a tool.

Comment: @BrianPeter to skip the -en processing just change `WHEN instr(c10,'-en.xml') > 0 THEN` to something that won't be found e.g. `WHEN instr(c10,'-zzzzen.xml') > 0 THEN` then the ELSE clause will be applied for all rows.

Comment: I made a .rar archive of my original database.  Before testing anything, I close the database, extract the original data over the old version, and reopen the database every time.  So I test every query with a fresh copy of the original data.  I'm using SQLite Expert Personal v5.3 (x64) for the queries/edits.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear or missed something... The database contains about 1/2 the records with the old strings that I am trying to convert, BUT ALSO already has about 1/2 the records with the strings in the correct format.  So the example you provided initially works on the old ones, but is overwriting the ones that were already in the correct format.

Comment: @BrianPeter I've changed the asnwer, i.e. the WHERE clause, this was exlcuding all rows as it was checking against c10 column which had changed due to the SET. Instead it now checks the original table (rather than table being worked on). ***So you need to change the table name from mytable in 2 places.***

Comment: Thank you @MikeT!  That final edit worked, it changed the old format records to the new format and left the ones that were already correct alone.  I really appreciate your help!